# Where is the "blog" part in S*?

Tags: discussion, blog, not-a-real-question

Regarding this "question":  [Google Chrome OS Review. What is your take?](https://superuser.com/questions/73130/google-chrome-os-review-what-is-your-take)
It looks like the user really put some effort into his ... lets call it article. In the comment section he refers to the [about page](https://superuser.com/about) where there is a "blog" part mentioned.
But somehow that whole thing doesn't seem to fit in there. I, too, expect questions that can be answered. This one is not a question that can be answered so, as mentioned in the comments, it's a candidate for a community wiki. But that way no reputation would be gained and thus there is no incentive to write such articles, i.e. to blog. (By now it's already "closed as not a real question".)

Is such content generally not meant to fit in here or did the user just present it the wrong way?

**Update:** Ok you say, it's not a blog. I understand and see it the same way. But then [this picture](http://sstatic.net/su/Img/stackoverflow-venn-diagram.png) is misleading, isn't it? The About Page says, there is only a tiny fraction of each 4 components, but the blog part has gone completely missing, then.

Comment: It's not a blog.  Blog entries disguised as "questions" typically get closed, except for some that get turned into CW for some odd reason (by some odd people?).  :-)

Comment: S* incorporates elements of a blog by being somewhere people can write stuff.  It doesn't include those elements of blogging that are angst-filled self-gratification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trilogy is for questions and answers.  "Discussion" questions (those with no practical "right" answer) go as CW because votes then are more just weak "yeah, that seems reasonable" rather than "this is the right answer", so you don't hand out rep for those.  Discussion questions, though, still need to have a focus, because otherwise it's just the "blogosphere" all over again -- rambling hither and yon wherever the fingers take thee.

The question you linked to isn't a question.  It is a blog post with a stupendously open-ended "question" at the end (which doesn't even really relate to most of the content presented).  It deserved closing, IMAO.

Answer (score 6):

My opinion: I don't think it belongs there. You can blog all you want on your blog, and then maybe use a link to that blog somewhere in a question or an answer **if it is relevant**, but otherwise, SU or any of the SO sites is not the place to put such articles.

Answer (score 3):

I agree is not a real question... Wait a minute, that was **MY!!** question, well yeah, I have to admit it is not a question. BUT!!

I was super excited about it. I have never had a blog because I don't feel like it.

I remember I joined StackOverflow because exactly this same picture:

[alt text http://sstatic.net/so/Img/stackoverflow-venn-diagram.png](http://sstatic.net/so/Img/stackoverflow-venn-diagram.png)

I saw it in the codinghorror blog  ( this:[entry](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001169.html) ) and since then I'm hooked.

So I wanted to share it, not on Reddit or other place, because those are communities I don't really use, but instead I thought about sharing it with S*'s

I guess that was a wrong idea.

**Answering your question**

The **Wiki** + **Digg/Reddit** + **Forum** part has gone tremendously well, while the blog part.. mmhh I think it should be **removed** from that image.

I have now "refactored" my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/73130/google-chrome-os-review-how-important-it-is-to-preserve-user-habits-closed), and copy/pasted the entry in [my blog](http://oscarreyes.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/google-chrome-os-review/) ( *"my blog"*.. hey that's sound funny, I guess that would be my  1st and last  entry )

You can now go back and vote to reopen that question.

Comment: IMHO, question is still too subjective and argumentative to re-open. I think since that blog post you mention has been published, the stackoverflow platform has much changed and evolved to be much more "Wiki" and "Forum", and much less "Digg/Reddit" and "Blog". Actually, those specific 'realms' (Digg/Reddit and Blog) were much less prominent from the beginning...

Comment: You really should have just given up on that question (although the number 73130 *does* have a nice ring to it) and asked a new question.  I'm not sure that a philosophical user interface question is really going to get good answers on SU, but at least now it's a discussion question with a reasonable boundary.

Answer (score -1):

Digg is community bookmarky thing and I don't really see any of that at SO. I guess some people might post a link as an answer (and then get told off for not including the content) and you could look at some of the very well written answers as blog posts.